# create a file (name.extension) by mime type

Tags: php

How to create a file (name_of_file . file_extension), by mime type? The list of mimes is dynamic.

Example:

```
MIME                   Extension
application/msword  |  .doc
text/plain          |  .txt
text/css            |  .css
```

I dont wanna use array("mime" => "extension");

I have the mime type, but i need the file extension.

Comment: Are you essentially asking for a dump of [mime type-to-extension](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml) in a tabled list? PHP also have [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) that you can use.

Comment: i dont wanna make a list of mimes and extensions

Comment: `i dont wanna use array("mime" => "extension");` - you have to use *some* kind of lookup table, every implemented method of doing this ever has some form of lookup table somewhere in it.

Comment: @andre: Then use the `finfo_file`?

Comment: @Brad Christie: the php on server is 5.0 =/

Comment: @Andre: How about [mime_content_type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) (which is available in 5, but has since been deprecated).

Comment: @AndréGadonski - Why the objection to using a look up table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid using a lookup table (at least avoid *you* having to define one) you can use [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

```
echo finfo_file('myfile.jpg', finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)); // output: image/jpg
```

If you're on 5.0, you may try [`mime_content_type`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) (But keep in mind this is deprecated, so if you're looking for upgrade-compatible, you may want to default to the new `finfo_file` when possible):

```
echo mime_content_type('myfile.jpg'); // output: image/jpg
```

---

```
// When possible, it will use upgraded finfo_file, but will default back
// to content_mime_type when necessary
function getMimeType($file){
  if (function_exists('finfo_file') && defined('FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE')){
    $return_mime = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    return finfo_file($file, $return_mime);
  }
  return content_mime_type($file);
}
```

Comment: nice! but, i need the file extension. i have the mime type.

Comment: @AndréGadonski: Then you're going to need some form of lookup table. Everything in PHP is to look up from file to mime, not the other way around.